# What is the command line syntax for custom stacks for the OSX Leopard dock?

Tags: macos, dock, stack

I know there is a command line syntax for adding custom stacks to the OSX Leopard dock besides the "Downloads" which comes by default.  What is it?

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/dockutil/

Comment: No I want the syntax to do it directly.  I want to learn Apple's syntax, not the syntax for a tool that produces the syntax for me.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't completely answer your question, [this page](http://www.tuaw.com/2008/09/16/terminal-tips-add-recent-applications-as-a-stack-on-dock/) has some info on how to add a "recent items" stack to the Dock. Maybe that will help you to figure out what the generic syntax for adding Stacks is?